# How to check if an LI from a UL has a string (where there are any number of UL)

Tags: java, selenium, parsing, xpath

Example 1: City is Calgary

```
<div class="listresults">
    <ul id="company_1" class="companylist">
        <li><b>HEATCRAFT Freezing LTD., a Division of Lennox Inc.</b></li>
        <li>#8 - 7797 - 98th Street S. E.</li>
        <li>Calgary,AB T9H 9S6</li>
        <li>(603) 252-6322</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="company_2" class="companylist">
        <li><b>SEARS INDOOR CLEAN WIND SERVICES (202222 ALBERTA LTD.)</b></li>
        <li>895 - 49 Avenue N. E.</li>
        <li>Calgary,AB T9E 9N4</li>
        <li>(603) 230-2629</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="company_3" class="companylist">
        <li><b>ARPI'S INDUSTRIES CANADA LTD., a Division of Lennox Inc.</b></li>
        <li>6895 - 40 Street S. E.</li>
        <li>Calgary,AB T9C 9W7</li>
        <li>(603) 236-2666</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="company_4" class="companylist">
        <li><b>SHEET Plastics WORKS</b></li>
        <li>P. O. Box 49089, 7740 - 98th St., S.E.</li>
        <li>Calgary,AB T9C 8W5</li>
        <li>(603) 279-0022</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Example 2: City is Aurora

```
<div class="listresults">
    <ul id="company_1" class="companylist">
        <li><b>SUMMERS AND SMITH ROOFING &amp; Freezing LTD.</b></li>
        <li>55 Industrial Parkway South</li>
        <li>Aurora,ON L4G 8Y5</li>
        <li>(905) 727-2323</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="company_2" class="companylist">
        <li><b>BEST CLIMATE Freezing AND ROOFING INC.</b></li>
        <li>68 Mugford Avenue</li>
        <li>Aurora,ON L4G 7H5</li>
        <li>(905) 713-3212</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Question: How can I check for any number of UL's in div class="listresults", the third LI will always contain %city. I do not necessarily need the text, I just need to validate that it has the %city. I would like this to be done by xPath.

This is what I have tried: (where city is either Calgary, or Aurora in the above examples)

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(String.format("//ul[@class='companylist']/td[3 and contains(text(), '%s')]", city)));
        for (WebElement element: elements) {
            System.out.println(element.getText());
        }
```

Even if I change my xPath to "//ul[@class='companylist']/td[3]" to just find the text from that TD, so I can parse it outside the driver, it does not return the TD field values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize the problem with my xPath was that in a UL, i am looking for a TD when I am actually looking for an LI. Oops. Thanks for the help everyone!

Slightly modified answer posted by Kiril S. solves the problem

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='companylist']/li[3]"));
for(WebElement element : elements) {
    if(element.text().contains(city)) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. There's a number of ways to do this, I would do it this way

```
//ul[@class='companylist']/li[3][contains(.,'Calgary')]
```

You can then substitute 'Calgary' with whatever the desired city, etc. is.

Note... your XPath contains `TD` which is a `TABLE` cell instead of using `LI` which is a list item in an unordered list (`UL`). That's actually why yours didn't work.